# Weird menu display on top-left on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, display

Sometimes a menu **displays on top-left of my screen**. I can't hide or click on it. It will appear until I log out. Is there anyone has the same problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix it but I found a way to prevent it.
Open **Setting** > **Devices** > **Keyboard** and disable the **Activate the window menu** shortcut.

[image]